# Programmatically defining variables

Tags: symbols, system-variables

I seems as though what I am interested in is [unconventional](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/516762), but I am interested in defining a number of different variables programmatically.

For example I can write a matrix of variables by doing:

```
Table[Symbol["\[Rho]" <> ToString@i <> ToString@j], {i, 5}, {j, 
   5}] // MatrixForm
```

But is it impossible for me to assign specific values to them?

Here's one of my attempts that doesn't work:

```
For[i = 0, i < 3, i++, Symbol["fish" <> ToString@i] = 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

It is much easier to use an indexed variable and use [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to display the variable any way that you want.

For example, to display `μ` as a subscripted variable

```
Format[μ[n_]] := Subscript[μ, n]
```

then

```
var = Array[μ, 5]
```

[image]

Assigning values is straightforward:

```
μ[1] = μ[4] = 3;
```

The result is

```
var
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While I like the recommendation of switching to the subscript formatting, does this completely answer the question for assigning values programmatically? It works for the for loop I specified, but I'm not sure it would work if I chose a more complicated example.  (for example, what about: For[i = 0, i < 3, i++, Symbol["fish" <> ToString@i] = 3i]?)

Comment: `(fish[#] = 3 #) & /@ Range[0, 2]` then look at say `fish[2]`

Comment: Interesting. Thanks a lot!